# Tcpdump: Sequence and acknowledgement number mismatch with libpcap

Tags: networking, network-programming, libpcap, tcpdump

I am writing an app where I am printing TCP sequence and ack numbers.
I ran tcpdump on the same box and the numbers do not match. Here is my
code, all headers and structures are from [sniffex.c](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c&ei=3_toUKOUK4XA9gTQ4oHoBA&usg=AFQjCNG06vPZLcb_gnMas5sM1m7uu5K53A&sig2=pdfscbubzfUEDSZdGEuwcQ)

```
void
got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{

    static int count = 1;                   /* packet counter */

    /* declare pointers to packet headers */
    const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
    const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
    const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            /* The TCP header */

    int size_ip;
    int size_tcp;
    int size_payload;

    count++;

    /* define ethernet header */
    ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

    /* define/compute ip header offset */
    ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
    size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
    if (size_ip < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
        return;
    }

    /* determine protocol */
    switch(ip->ip_p) {
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("   Protocol: TCP\n");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("   Protocol: UDP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_ICMP:
            printf("   Protocol: ICMP\n");
            return;
        case IPPROTO_IP:
            printf("   Protocol: IP\n");
            return;
        default:
            printf("   Protocol: unknown\n");
            return;
    }


    /* define/compute tcp header offset */
    tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
    size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
    if (size_tcp < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "Packet# " << count << " S " << tcp->th_seq << " A "
<< tcp->th_ack << "\n";

}
```

And this prints:

```
Packet# 2 S 1063936835 A 1371648504
Packet# 3 S 1080714051 A 1975693816
Packet# 4 S 1080714051 A 1975693816
Packet# 5 S 141321027 A 2730734072
Packet# 6 S 2960220995 A 2730734072
Packet# 7 S 1484219203 A 2730734072
Packet# 8 S 8217411 A 2730734072
Packet# 9 S 2827117379 A 2730734072
Packet# 10 S 1351115587 A 2730734072
```

I ran tcpdump to record a pcap file as:

```
# sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 -S -n -w cache.cap 'tcp and src port 80'
```

And then inspected it with

```
# sudo tcpdump -S -ttttnnr cache.cap
reading from file cache.cap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
2012-09-30 18:52:58.110398 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [S.], seq 1130588735, ack 4172398929, win 14480, options [mss
1460,sackOK,TS val 71597136 ecr 71595534,nop,wscale 3], length 0
2012-09-30 18:52:58.110925 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [.], ack 4172399221, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 71597136
ecr 71595534], length 0
2012-09-30 18:52:58.116146 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [P.], seq 1130588736:1130589192, ack 4172399221, win 1944,
options [nop,nop,TS val 71597137 ecr 71595534], length 456
2012-09-30 18:52:58.173321 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [.], seq 1130589192:1130590640, ack 4172399522, win 2078,
options [nop,nop,TS val 71597152 ecr 71595549], length 1448
2012-09-30 18:52:58.173388 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [.], seq 1130590640:1130592088, ack 4172399522, win 2078,
options [nop,nop,TS val 71597152 ecr 71595549], length 1448
2012-09-30 18:52:58.173517 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [.], seq 1130592088:1130593536, ack 4172399522, win 2078,
options [nop,nop,TS val 71597152 ecr 71595549], length 1448
2012-09-30 18:52:58.173583 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [.], seq 1130593536:1130594984, ack 4172399522, win 2078,
options [nop,nop,TS val 71597152 ecr 71595549], length 1448
2012-09-30 18:52:58.173620 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [.], seq 1130594984:1130596432, ack 4172399522, win 2078,
options [nop,nop,TS val 71597152 ecr 71595549], length 1448
2012-09-30 18:52:58.173656 IP 192.168.122.11.80 > 192.168.122.22.7001:
Flags [.], seq 1130596432:1130597880, ack 4172399522, win 2078,
options [nop,nop,TS val 71597152 ecr 71595549], length 1448
```

The sequence and ack numbers do not match. What am I missing here?

In my application, the filter is same 'tcp and src port 80'

**EDIT**
I changed

```
std::cout << "Packet# " << count << " S " << tcp->th_seq << " A "
    << tcp->th_ack << "\n";
```

to

```
 std::cout << "Packet# " << count << " S " << ntohl(tcp->th_seq) << " A "
    << ntohl(tcp->th_ack) << "\n";
```

Now the output is

```
Packet# 2 S 1384921720 A 3111642711
Packet# 3 S 1384921721 A 3111643003
Packet# 4 S 1384921721 A 3111643003
Packet# 5 S 1384922177 A 3111643304
Packet# 6 S 1384923625 A 3111643304
Packet# 7 S 1384925073 A 3111643304
Packet# 8 S 1384926521 A 3111643304
Packet# 9 S 1384927969 A 3111643304
Packet# 10 S 1384929417 A 3111643304
```

Still does not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only recording half the traffic, i.e. in one direction. The ACKs are for the part you aren't recording. Try a filter that includes destination port 80.

Comment: For example, try just `tcp port 80`, without `src` or `dst`.